# How can I check if a QString contains only "invisible" characters?

Tags: qt, special-characters, qstring

I would like to check if a `QString` is made up of only non-printable or non-visible characters. The `QString` could contain unicode...

I imagine a regular expression may work, but I have no idea how to create such a regex.

How can I check if a `QString` contains only "invisible" characters ? (space, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`...)

My "brute force" try

```
bool checkIfEmpty(const QString &contents) const
{
    for(QString::const_iterator itr(contents.begin()); itr != contents.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(*itr != '\n' && *itr != '\r' && *itr != ' ' && *itr != '\t')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QString` is made up of UTF-16 code units, puzzlingly named `QChar`, not characters. A character may be represented by one or more Unicode code points. Generally speaking, you'd need to iterate over the string and process all surrogate pairs to get Unicode code points (in UTF-32/UCS-4) through `QChar::surrogateToUcs4`. You then get `QChar::category` for these, and check what they are. This could be represented in a regex that still operates on `QChar`s, though.

Thankfully, all of the non-printing code points are represented as a single code unit in UTF-16, so by looking at each `QChar` in isolation you can tell what it is.

And, `QChar::isSpace()` knows all that, and `QRegExp` matches such characters under the `\s` category.

Thus, your check reduces to:

```
bool isWhiteSpace(const QString & str)
{
  return QRegExp("\\s*").exactMatch(str);
}
```

It'd be useful to retain the regular expression as a class member, since its construction from a pattern is expensive:

```
// C++11, Qt 5
class C {
  QRegExp m_whiteSpace { QStringLiteral("\\s*") };
public:
  bool isWhiteSpace(const QString & str) const {
    return m_whiteSpace.exactMatch(str);
  }
};

// C++98, Qt 5
class C {
  QRegExp m_whiteSpace;
public:
  C() : m_whiteSpace(QStringLiteral("\\s*")) {}
  bool isWhiteSpace(const QString & str) const {
    return m_whiteSpace.exactMatch(str);
  }
};

// C++98, Qt 4
class C {
  QRegExp m_whiteSpace;
public:
  C() : m_whiteSpace(QLatin1String("\\s*")) {}
  bool isWhiteSpace(const QString & str) const {
    return m_whiteSpace.exactMatch(str);
  }
};
```

> The QString could contain unicode

Not could. Does. Always. That's what a `QString` is. It is a container for UTF-16 code units. They "are" Unicode, in the sense of having an interpretation defined in the Unicode standard. The Latin-1 block is no less Unicode than the Devanagari block.

What you meant was probably that the string's contents aren't limited to any subset of Unicode code points or blocks.

Comment: I marked this as answer because I had just found that I could do this regexp `static const QRegExp blankRegExp("\\S");` and then check `return !str.contains(blankRegExp);` - I could not get the declaration of `m_whiteSpace` as you wrote it to build.

Comment: @Thalia This is the C++11 value initialization syntax. You probably need to port it back to C++98 and use the initializer list instead. Since you do use an older C++ compiler that doesn't dig thread safety, the `static const QRegExp` is a surefire way to die a quick death once you start using it from other threads. I'd simply avoid these whenever possible as a matter of habit.

Answer (score 6):

try this approach

```
bool checkIfEmpty(const QString contents) const
{
     if(contents.trimmed()=="") return true;
     else return false;
}
```

please note that this could be used only if you meant by "no printable" is space or tab characters

Comment: Also: contents.trimmed().isEmpty()